# Laravel 5.4 : Fatal error: Uncaught ReflectionException: Class App\Exceptions\Handler does not exist in

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

`PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught ReflectionException: Class App\Exceptions\Handler does not exist in /var/www/html/lsapp/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:788`

I'm new to laravel and I've got this error while following laravel from scratch from Traversy on youtube. I chose version 5.4 so I can easily follow along with the tutorial, everything works fine.

Except that I can't run any composer, artisan command. I don't have any idea where this comes from as everything was working fine till the moment I wanted to create a migration for the user_id foreign key (I still don't understand why he has to use a migration for that fk)

I've read similar posts in here and others forums, tried solutions suggested but nothing seems to fix it. I've checked for misspelling classes, case sensitivity and everything seem okay.

But that error convince me that everything is not okay!

Any hint, idea or solution
Thanks.

Comment: Do you have a `app/Exceptions/Handler.php` file?

Comment: Yes, I do have it.

Comment: Do a `composer du`. If problem does not solve, the issue can be anywhere. I advise you to pick up a tutorial teaching at least version 6. All previous are truly deprecated in contrast to what newer versions offer.

Comment: I did and it said that carbon 1 is deprecated. I tried an upgrade and failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
Trying another upgrade as I've been suggested to and it didn't wrok.
Same error appeared on php artisan optimize throwing this error
`Script php artisan optimize handling the post-update-cmd event returned with error code 255`

Comment: I think it would be better to follow the latest version of laravel for your learning, if you like video tutorials then a good place to get started is laracast. For your error I would suggest you to delete the vendor folder and run `composer update --prefer-source` also make sure that your php version is 7.1 or above, ofcourse 5.4 will work with php version 5.4 and above. You don't have to worry about upgrading carbon. What server are you using, Are you using vagrant or xampp or laragon. Also mention your OS

Comment: That what I did, I'm following Laracasts one but I was in the lasts videos of Traversy tutorial. Everything worked fine from beginning ... sure I messed something somewhere but anyway. I tried your command and whenever I try to run composer update it throws the same error at php artisan optimize.
I'm using php 7.3 with apache server on a debian OS but I ll give up on it and continue with laracasts.

Comment: Did you find any solution ?